# Computer freezing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, cpu, freeze

thanks in advance for your time.
i’m experiencing plenty of computer freeze these days. My system runs Windows 10 on a quad core machine (X4 860K).
The *freezing experience* shows my computer that keeps running, the whole machine is still running, while I can’t use any peripheral anymore. The screen shows the last task opened and my only option is to turn it off using the case button.
I read that the previous version of Windows 10 had some issues and use to froze once in a while, but I downloaded the latest version and it doesn’t help.
I have already performed the CHKDSK on both my SSD drives, and they seem to be okay.
The temperature is really low now that I added a new dissipator for the CPU, is around 28° idle.
what I’m asking here is:
which one is the part that more often is the cause of this kind of freezing issue?
I am going to build a new machine soon and I’m planning to use the same Power supply, video card and also both of the SSDs, could they be part of the issue?
Thank you very much, sorry to bother you.

Comment: In the Task Manager, can you see a high consumption of CPU, memory, or disk usage? This would be first steps. After that, if needing to dig in deeper, open up the Resource Monitor and try to isolate the process which is clogging the pipes. Otherwise, there is a possibility that the operating system or application causing the issue is throwing errors caught by the Event Viewer—opening this will help identify critical errors.

Comment: To see if the issue is hardware or Windows OS related, boot from a live USB with another OS, e.g. Linux. If this works well, then the issue is either a failing HDD or the Windows OS.